# PHP sum each loop value

Tags: php

I wanted to make a simple calculations to summarized what I purchased.

Using `$_GET` every time the value is updated it should save in an array then when 'start' is executed, it gives the sum. Sorry the codes here are just googled and I'm not really a programmer. I don't know how to combine the two sets of code (array + sum).

```
$number = $_GET ['input'];
$arr = array ($number);

$data = array($arr);
foreach ($tareas as $tarea) {
    $data[] = $tarea;
}
var_dump($data);

$sum = 0;
foreach($group as $key=>$arr) {
    $sum+= $arr;
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: To get the sum of an array you can use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum). Without knowing your `input` data we can't really help any different as you're not telling us what the values look like.

Comment: I saw that array_sum. Lets say I input 3, then refreshed the site and input 2. If start is executed it should give me 5.

Comment: What is your code doing? I can't see what it's doing. You have unassigned variables everywhere

Comment: @Seed85 So what you're searching for is saving data in cookies or session variables (you can google both of these to give you thousands of tutorials) and fetching whatever you have saved in the cookie/sessionvar in order to add to that.

Comment: By now, this looks like a simple cart. Via POST site.com/index.php?input=3 for example. then POST site.com/index.php?input=2. now to get the sum, GET site.com/index.php?start=yes it should return 5

Comment: @h2ooooooo I think your second answer is what I needed. I'll look it up and let you know any progress  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I got this code from [withinweb.com](https://www.withinweb.com/info/a-shopping-cart-using-php-sessions-code/) and modified to make it simpler.

```
<?php session_start();

$products = array($_GET["prod"]);
$amounts = array($_GET ["cost"]);

if ( !isset($_SESSION["total"]) ) {

$_SESSION["total"] = 0;
for ($i=0; $i< count($products); $i++) {
//   $_SESSION["qty"][$i] = 0;
$_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = 0;
  }
}

//---------------------------
//Reset
if ( isset($_GET['reset']) )
{
if ($_GET["reset"] == 'true')
{
unset($_SESSION["qty"]); //The quantity for each product
unset($_SESSION["amounts"]); //The amount from each product
unset($_SESSION["total"]); //The total cost
unset($_SESSION["cart"]); //Which item has been chosen
  }
}

//---------------------------
//Add
if ( isset($_GET["add"]) )
   {
   $i = $_GET["add"];
   $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$i] + 1;
   $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $amounts[$i] * $qty;
   $_SESSION["cart"][$i] = $i;
   $_SESSION["qty"][$i] = $qty;
   }

  //---------------------------
  //Delete
  if ( isset($_GET["delete"]) )
   {
   $i = $_GET["delete"];
   $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$i];
   $qty--;
   $_SESSION["qty"][$i] = $qty;
   //remove item if quantity is zero
   if ($qty == 0) {
    $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = 0;
    unset($_SESSION["cart"][$i]);
   }
  else
  {
  $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $amounts[$i] * $qty;
   }
  }

  //cart
  if ( isset($_SESSION["cart"]) ) {

  $total = 0;
 foreach ( $_SESSION["cart"] as $i ) {

 echo '' . $products[$_SESSION["cart"][$i]] . ' - ' . $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] . '<br>';

 $total = $total + $_SESSION["amounts"][$i];
 }
 $_SESSION["total"] = $total;

echo'
<br>
Total : ' . $total . '
'; 

}

?>
```

When I input ?add=0&prod=apple&cost=100, it gives me:

```
apple - 100

Total : 100
```

But when I add another session, ?add=1&prod=orange&cost=200 it doesn't give the right answer.

```
orange - 100
- 0

Total : 100
```

It should return me this value, I'm puzzled where could be the error.

```
apple - 100
orange - 200

Total : 300
```

Yes, I'm not a coder, but trying to solve a big problem.. :) Thanks for those who help.

Comment: You're better off posting this as a new question as it doesn't get bumped to the top of the question list and accounts for an answer rather than a question. :-)